# Put replace string in parentheses

Tags: php, str-replace

Hi i wanna to put string or numbers in parentheses

```
$var = 'HELLO' ;

str_replace("$var","?????", $value);
```

//
I need change `$var` to this :

```
$var = (HELLO)
```

Comment: why not concat the brackets ? like  $var = 'Hello'; $var = "({$var})";

Comment: HELLO is an variable from an array . i dont know all variables value

Comment: you should edit your question to present the actual data

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Just put `$var` in parentheses:

```
$value = str_replace($var, "($var)", $value);
```

Comment: I think you mean :$value = str_replace($var, "($var)", $var);

Comment: No, assuming `$value` has a string with `$var` in it.  Otherwise it would just be `$var = "($var)";`

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're asking. For this simple task, you can simply append the parenthesis:

```
$var = 'HELLO';
$var = '('.$var.')';
echo $var; // value is (HELLO)
```

If you have to use `str_replace`, then here's how:

```
$var = 'HELLO';
$var = str_replace($var, '('.$var.')', $var);
echo $var; // value is (HELLO)
```

str_replace accepts three parameters. Search, replace, and subject. The search parameter is used to look for a string inside of the subject. In this case, the subject and the string are identical (`$var`). The replace field is what you want to replace the search with. In this example, we are replacing the $var with itself and then appending parenthesis to it.

That's why I gave my first answer because it's much simpler. You just do some string concatenation instead of replacing a variable with itself.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use substr_replace instead of str_replace and then you gonna have something like this (for putting position I suggest to use sizeof($var) instead of real number ) :

```
$var = substr_replace($var, '(', 0, 0);
$var = substr_replace($var, ')', 6, 0);
```